# What are top level statements in C#? What is their use?

Tags: c#

I just created my first .NET 6 console app, and instead of the default,

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I got:

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

And even when there's no class, the program runs! I took a look at the link provided in the comments, but I don't know if this is a new feature or an old one. If this is a new feature, does that mean C# will be allowing C-style programming hereafter?

Comment: Well it is a C#9/10 feature [top level statement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#top-level-programs) and [global and implicit usings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/)

Comment: And did you see https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information?

Comment: Compiler magic, resulting in inconsistent syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a new feature of C# 9 or 10. [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) says following:

> Top-level statements enable you to avoid the extra ceremony required by placing your program's entry point in a static method in a class. The typical starting point for a new console application looks like the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

> The preceding code is the result of running the dotnet new console command and creating a new console application. Those 11 lines contain only one line of executable code. You can simplify that program with the new top-level statements feature. That enables you to remove all but two of the lines in this program:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is very little use for this.  Consider a 10,000+ line program.  You can eliminate 11 lines from the Program.cs file which hides what it is doing and makes it look unlike every other file in the program.  This was such a bad idea, now VS allows a check box to turn this abomination off.  I suggest you use that and make all your files consistent.

According to Microsoft, "This feature simplifies what's needed to begin exploring new ideas. You can use top-level statements for scripting scenarios, or to explore. Once you've got the basics working, you can start refactoring the code and create methods, classes, or other assemblies for reusable components you've built. Top-level statements do enable quick experimentation and beginner tutorials. They also provide a smooth path from experimentation to full programs."  This is terrible.  I almost never keep experimental code around in the production stuff (and you shouldn't either).  Also, the template writes those 11 lines for you so what exactly are we saving or speeding up here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).